# VBA Loop not working for recursive people

Tags: excel, vba

We are trying to make a Loop to copy/past data of all our people (SALARIE 1, SALARIE 2 ...).
We have difficult to make the loop working, here is our code.

I specify that the code works perfectly without the loop (with EMPLOYEE 1 only).
With the loop, the line "rngRow2 = rngFound2.Row" return an error.

Could you help us, or give us some road to follow ? :)

Have a great day !

```
Sub importData()

Dim dataCopy As Worksheet, dataPaste As Worksheet
Dim rngRow As Long, rngColumn As Long, StartCell As Range, LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, wholeRange As Range
Dim rngRow2 As Long, rngColumn2 As Long, StartCell2 As Range, LastRow2 As Long, LastColumn2 As Long, wholeRange2 As Range

Set dataCopy = Workbooks("ANNEXE1_ETAT_RECAP_DEPENSES_2019(511134).xlsx").Worksheets("Dépenses de personnel")
Set dataPaste = Workbooks("Annexe 4. PA000XXX_ANNEXE CSF_TABLEAU CONTROLE v23.4.xlsm").Worksheets("DEPENSES PERSONNEL")

For i = 1 To 65

    Set rngFound = dataCopy.Range("A:A").Find("SALARIE " & i, LookIn:=xlValues)
    rngRow = rngFound.Row
    rngColumn = rngFound.Column
    Set StartCell = dataCopy.Cells(rngRow, rngColumn)
    LastRow = dataCopy.Cells.Find("Décembre", After:=StartCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
    LastColumn = StartCell.End(xlToRight).Column
    
    Set wholeRange = dataCopy.Range(StartCell, dataCopy.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))


    Set rngFound2 = dataPaste.Range("A:A").Find("SALARIE " & i, LookIn:=xlValues)
    rngRow2 = rngFound2.Row
    rngColumn2 = rngFound2.Column
    Set StartCell2 = dataPaste.Cells(rngRow2, rngColumn2)
    LastRow2 = dataPaste.Cells.Find("Décembre", After:=StartCell2, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row
    LastColumn2 = StartCell2.End(xlToRight).Column
    
    Set wholeRange2 = dataPaste.Range(StartCell2, dataPaste.Cells(LastRow2, LastColumn2))
    
wholeRange.Range(dataCopy.Cells(2, 2), dataCopy.Cells(13, 4)).Copy _
    wholeRange2.Range(dataPaste.Cells(8, 2), dataPaste.Cells(19, 4))
   
Next i
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does it error on?

Comment: Hi, it is the line "rngRow2 = rngFound2.Row"

Comment: Well, add that to your question, don't leave it in a comment.

Comment: I specify that the code works perfectly without the loop (with EMPLOYEE 1 only)

Comment: Up to you, you are the one wanting help....

Comment: It's done, thank you :)

Comment: Let me look into my crystal ball: You get an Runtime error 91 - object variable not set.  And that is because the `find` coudn't find one of the strings and therefore `rngFound2` is set to Nothing. Have you checked the content of `rngFound2` in the debugger? Have you checked what the content of `i` is when you get that error? Have you checked that `dataPaste` contains that string?

Comment: What is the error message when the macro fails? Does the code fail on the first iteration of the loop (when i = 1), or on a subsequent one? What happens if the loop is `For i = 1 to 1`? I think you may want to check to make sure `rngFound2` exists before trying to get its row.

Comment: Your cristal ball is almost good :), it is a Runtime error 424. It fail at the first iteration, the i return well "1", but rngFound2 return 0

Comment: Okay, it was because of a merged cell... Thanks guys and sorry for missed your time...